# make the link clickable area equal to the size of the parent element (<li>), even if the parent has padding

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I have a menu item with links within each entry.

I would like to make clickable the entire tag `<li>` to run the link.

```
 <li style="padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
 <li>
```

I searched on the forum and I understand that to achieve (in part) what I want, i should add:

```
 a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

but in my `<li>` i have padding and so the clickable area of link it isn't equal to size of `<li>`. I tried to delete padding of `<li>` and add it to `<a>`, but then the clickable area comes out of tag li....

How can I solve the problem?

thanks

**EDIT**

this is a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/zgqyLuq4/1/
The clickable area of link COMES OUT its parent (`<li>`)

Comment: Taking the padding from `<li>` to `<a>` should mean both elements are the same size. There must be other factors such as CSS rules being applied to the `<li>` that needs resetting.

Comment: but the clickable area COMES OUT of tag li

Comment: When you say 'comes out' do you mean it is clickable outside the `<a>` element?

Comment: You really need to share a jsfiddle or similar with more of your HTML and CSS to be able to fix this problem.

Comment: @Ryan outside its parent (so the `<li>`), however see the jsfiddle: in the example i taking the padding from li to "<a>" but nothing... http://jsfiddle.net/zgqyLuq4/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the `a` tag have the padding not the `li`.
if in case you have:

```
li {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

make it on the `a` tag like this:

```
li > a {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the clickable area COMES OUT of tag li

Comment: That is because when using display: block on a element, you have to define display: inline-block or block on the li element

Comment: i tried also as you say but nothing... see the jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/zgqyLuq4/1/

Comment: in the fiddle the click able area is exactly the whole dark area and it's right, so what's really the issue here?

Comment: Excuse me ... but are you serious? Looks good .. (if I place the cursor slightly off to the right of the right edge you can see that it is still clickable, even though we are out of the tag them)

Comment: Remove width:100% from your a tag and it will be as you want. and please accept the answer.